# Forward an email in the reply to another email through Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I am using Gmail.

I know how to forward an email received from A to B, by simply choosing the forward option for the email to be forwarded, and putting B's address there.

But I wonder how to forward an email received from A to B, within a reply to another email received from B? Or what do people usually do alternatively in such a case?

Comment: It appears, Gmail (at least on the web), now supports this. https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9696522?hl=en (**Reply to an email with an attached email** in the bottom)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think copy and paste is your only option here. There is (to my knowledge) no way of attaching another email to a new one in gmail.

Comment: Thanks! What about in other webmails or web clients, besides gmail?

Comment: @Tim: Gmail is one of the most popular email clients, so ...

Comment: Can't say I've got much experience with other email clients, aside from Outlook. I know in Outlook you can attach other emails to a new email, therefore you might be able to use this function in Hotmail. However I don't suggest going to the 'dark side' yet.

Comment: I have not seen this feature in yahoo mail, Office 365 or outlook web access.

Comment: @Tim I think you'll have to mark this answer as the correct one, because this is your only option. When you click forward copy everything and past it in the reply of the other mail.. that would happen even if you had a build in option. Some clients doing that by attaching the email as file.. something is not really practical anyway using Gmail..

Comment: @Lipis: "something is not really practical anyway using Gmail." What else are really practical?

Comment: You can download the email and attach it to the email thread

Comment: Warning: this often fails on messages containing embedded images. The result looks fine before Send, then after, the images are missing.

Answer (score 3):

Best way I found is to hit 'print all' in the email you want to forward and save as PDF. Then simply attach the PDF to your reply.

Comment: Warning: this loses most of the header and attachments.

Answer (score 2):

Email clients usually group emails by title (and other stuff).

So you are able to forward an email in Gmail, **as a reply in another thread**, if you **edit the subject** to the same exact subject on the other thread (this will maintain images and other attachments properly!).

In this case, your are actually **moving** your email, so it won't show as a "forwarded email" in the original thread.

Just confirmed it works, so it might help other people. It should work with other clients such as Outlook too.

*I hate receiving emails > with attached emails > with attached other stuff*

Comment: I tried to do that while prefixing `Re: ` to the subject as it seems how all "linked" threads look like. It did not work in GMail. It does not appear as a reply to a person I wanted to reply to. I don't know how said person sees it though.

Comment: I too believe it often fails. Identical subject is not necessarily sufficient to join a new message into an existing thread.